# Weird conversion of y axis scale

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, area

I am trying to plot up really basic area plots of time and different metal production. For some  reason, the y scale on P1 is working, but the y scales on P2 and P3 are being changed. I have done everything I can think of - going back into the csv to check how the data are formatted, checking how the file looks when it is loaded into R and nothing seems to be working. I have another 4 plots which this has worked perfectly fine on so I am confused! The plot is coming out like this: [![image][1]][1]

Thanks if you can help

Here is my code :

```
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_bw(10))
setwd("/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/R/Mining/NSW")
copper<-read.csv("copper1.csv",header=TRUE)
lead<-read.csv("lead.csv",header=TRUE)
zinc<-read.csv("zinc.csv",header=TRUE)

p1<-ggplot(copper, aes(x=year, y=tonnes)) +
  geom_area(fill="#7698B8")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())+
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  labs(y = "Copper production (tonnes)", x = "Year")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1887,2008),breaks=seq(1887,2008,10))+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
p1

p2<-ggplot(lead, aes(x=year, y=tonnes)) +
  geom_area(fill="#2F67A9")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())+
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  labs(y = "Lead production (tonnes)", x = "Year")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1887,2008),breaks=seq(1887,2008,10))+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
p2

p3<-ggplot(zinc, aes(x=year, y=tonnes)) +
  geom_area()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())+
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  labs(y = "Zinc production (tonnes)", x = "Year")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1887,2008),breaks=seq(1887,2008,10))
p3

library(patchwork)

p1/p2/p3

structure(list(year = 1888:1893, tonnes = c(25L, 33L, 178L, 481L, 
579L, 187L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

structure(list(year = 1887:1892, tonnes = c(10073L, 18453L, 27704L, 
33380L, 69614L, 61839L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

structure(list(year = 1897:1902, tonnes = c(10329L, 6198L, 48043L, 
35519L, 37519L, 29903L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")


  


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgoIo.png
```

Comment: Hi Sophie, what do you mean by scales changed?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the y scales on P2 and P3 are being changed"? Additionally wouldn't it be easier to use facetting for this kind of plot?

Comment: Hi Stefan and Duck so it should be a scale of absolute numbers but it is converting to values such as 2e+05 , 3e+05 etc

Comment: I have added a photo if that helps

Comment: Does adding this help? scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE))

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much that worked!

Answer (score 1):

If the scale is the issue, also try this, in addition to the smart advice of **@JordanHackett**:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
#Plots
p1<-ggplot(copper, aes(x=year, y=tonnes)) +
  geom_area(fill="#7698B8")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())+
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  labs(y = "Copper production (tonnes)", x = "Year")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1887,2008),breaks=seq(1887,2008,10))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
p1

p2<-ggplot(lead, aes(x=year, y=tonnes)) +
  geom_area(fill="#2F67A9")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())+
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  labs(y = "Lead production (tonnes)", x = "Year")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1887,2008),breaks=seq(1887,2008,10))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
p2

p3<-ggplot(zinc, aes(x=year, y=tonnes)) +
  geom_area()+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())+
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  labs(y = "Zinc production (tonnes)", x = "Year")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1887,2008),breaks=seq(1887,2008,10))
p3
#Bind plots
p1/p2/p3
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help!